# React Router v4 Pass Location to Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In the `location`'s [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) it says:

> Finally, you can pass a location to the following components: Route Switch
>
> This will prevent them from using the actual location in the router’s state. This is useful for animation and pending navigation, or any time you want to trick a component into rendering at a different location than the real one.

Does anyone know an example with the above?